# Groovy TemplateEngine - function for markup creation

Tags: groovy, template-engine

I'm a JS programmer trying to write some Groovy code (with no Java background at all). I need to write some templates using Groovy, so I created a function in order to avoid repetition. My goal is to be able to pass html objects to the function (for example: `p()`, `div()`, `span()` and so on), but is isn't working as I expected:

**The function**

```
void addon ( addonType, mainHolder, content ) {
  div( class: "addon " + addonType ) {
    div( class: "addon-main" ) {
      div( class: "addon-main-holder" ) {
        yieldUnescaped mainHolder
      }
    }

    div( class: "addon-content" ) {
        yieldUnescaped content
    }
  }
}
```

**Doesn't works**:

```
[...]
  body {
    addon( 'addon-warning', p('Lorem Ipsum'), p('Dolor sit amet consectetur') )
  }
[...]
```

**Works**:

```
[...]
  body {
    addon( 'addon-warning', '<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>', '<p>Dolor sit amet consectetur</p>') )
  }
[...]
```

I tried some variations, using `yield` rather than `yieldUnescaped`, but no success. Is it possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is little confusing as you mentioned something does not work and something works. So, not clear the actual question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to pass in further DSL-based tags into your `addon` function, I'd pass closure to that function instead.  This is an simplified, self containing version (which makes it bit harder to read, as the template is in a string; take a look at the `XXX` comments):

```
import groovy.text.markup.*

def config = new TemplateConfiguration()
def engine = new MarkupTemplateEngine(config)
def template = engine.createTemplate('''
html {
    body {
        addon("Hello World", { // XXX: pass a closure
            p("Lorem Ipsum")
            p("Lorem Ipsum")
            p("Lorem Ipsum")
        })
    }
}

void addon(title, content) {
    h1(title)
    div {
        content() // XXX call the closure
    }
}
''')
Writable output = template.make([:])
println output
// => <html><body><h1>Hello World</h1><div><p>Lorem Ipsum</p><p>Lorem Ipsum</p><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div></body></html>
```